# Program to print numbers in stdout

Tags: java

I was asked this question in one of my interviews. I was wondering if this is some kind of a trick question or is there something different I have to consider about it.

**Question:** Write code that counts from 1 to 10 and outputs each value to stdout.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: seems pretty straightforward...were there additional constraints or is that the question exactly?

Comment: Why are _your_ thoughts? What did you answer at the interview?

Comment: If you consider that a trick question, I'd say programming is not your cup of tea. **Edit** nvm I though you sai **tricky** lol

Comment: I doubt that was a trick question.  That's probably just how they weed out the "oh...  Word doesn't count as programming?" applicants.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html

Comment: @Corbin: That link was awesome :)

Comment: Eh, I think it's kind of depressing.  The 199/200 applicants don't know how to program thing is why companies are forced to ask 'trick' questions like this one.  I somehow doubt other fields ever have people apply who are like "Oh...  You need to know how to drive to be a truck driver?"  :)

Comment: Well, I was thinking on the lines that I might have better chances of getting a new job now :P ;)

Comment: Ah, I guess in that way it is encouraging then.  Though you'd be surprised how often people get hired who should not.  It's a weird industry.... lol

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the question was meant to see *how* you would solve this, even if it appears to be simple.

Obvious solution:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
   System.out.println(i);
```

Alternative solution:

```
int i = 1;

while (i <= 10)
{
   System.out.println(i);

   i++;
}
```

Perhaps if you had given the alternate solution above, your interviewer would have asked you why you chose this approach instead of the more obvious one.

Comment: Thanks, I did give both these. Wanted to give one using switch case and also with a `goto` statement in `C` :P

Answer (score 1):

just recursive way of doing it.

```
   void display(int i){

     if(i==0){
     return;
}else{
    System.out.println(i);
    display((--i));
    }
 }
```

call the above method with display(10)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of interview questions like that are asked only to see that you can actually code a for-loop in the language.  Many applicants can't.

[Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) has noted this a number of times.

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= 10)
{
  System.out.println(i++);
}
```